# Allow user to search and scroll to the ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-search

I have a custom ListView set up in my app.

I am not sure how or if it's possible to do but I want to know how can I have the Android search icon to allow user to search within the ListView. So as the search becomes relevant, the ListView scrolls to that position and changes the background drawable.

I am looking to implement the search inside the ActionBar like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the content provider component for your application. The "private" content provider will allow you to do "custom search" like you desire. As per documentation:

```
However, you do need your own provider to provide custom search suggestions in your own application.
```

The [NotePad](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) example can provide you with a good starting point on implementing a "private" content provider. By "private", i mean that you are not sharing the ListView data with any other app or process running on your device or remotely.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to implement a `Filter` simply by `implements Filter` to your `ListView` adapter.
2. Write how you will filter your results inside `performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)` method.
3. All you need is to make a call inside your `SearchView` query text listeners.
4. Invalidate the `ListView` with filtered results. Or get position of relevant item inside the Adapter data, and scroll using `mListView.smoothScrollToPosition(int position)`